# ICustomTypeDescriptor: When will GetProperties(Attribute[]) be called?

Tags: c#

By reading the MSDN article for ICustomTypeDescriptor http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx
I was unable to find a solid explanation of the difference of
`GetProperties()` and
`GetProperties(Attribute[])`

What attributes are used for the second method and how does the descriptor decided whether it calls `GetProperties` with or without the `Attribute` array.

(I've ported some code and the property grid in the old code used to call `GetProperties(Attributes[])` however the new code does only call the `GetProperties` without the attributes and I do not see what influences this)

Comment: Did you read the description of how the property filter works?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3yx7k228.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was unable to find a solid explanation of the difference of
>   `GetProperties()` and `GetProperties(Attribute[])`

The main difference is that `GetProperties()` returns all properties defined on the type implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` while `GetProperites(Attributes [] attributes)` returns a list of properties which are attributed with at least one of the attributes in the `Attribute[] attributes` parameter.

Check this sample implementation which uses `GetProperties()` to get the list of properties then filters it against the Attributes[] array.

```
public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in this.GetProperties())
            {
                bool include = false;
                foreach (Attribute searchAttribute in attributes)
                {
                    if (descriptor.Attributes.Contains(searchAttribute))
                    {
                        include = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (include)
                {
                    descriptors.Add(descriptor);
                }
            }
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(descriptors.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

> What attributes are used for the second method and how does the
>   descriptor decided whether it calls GetProperties with or without the
>   Attribute array.

The attributes used are chosen by the client code which uses [`TypeDesciptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) to get the list of properties.

For example the PropertyGrid control which is used in visual studio uses this mechanism to group properties on the selected object into categories, when you select a TextBox for example on the design canvas then properties for that TextBox are displayed in the PropertyGrid and categorized into Layout, Font, Miscellaneous, etc ...

This is achieved by annotating those properties in the TextBox class with the [`Category`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx) attribute and then `TypeDescriptor` calls `GetProperties(Attributes [] attributes)` on the TextBox class pasing `Category` in the array and the TextBox returns all properties which have the `Category` attribute on them.